# SQL Server queries with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have old program with access database. I want rewrite it to MS ACCESS. In queries u have text value `mm/yyyy` in query how to convert it to datetime from string?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to rewrite Access query to SQLserver or Acess to Access. In the second case remove the SQLserver tag, if its Access to SQLServer correct your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a nvarchar(100)
SET @a = '12052013'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@a,2) + '/' + 
       SUBSTRING(@a,3,2) + '/' + RIGHT(@a,4),101)
```

outputs this

```
 --2013-12-05 00:00:00.000
```